# What all carries into New Game+?

Tags: persona-5

I'm coming close to finishing my first playthrough of Persona 5 and I'm already planning my New Game+ playthrough where I'm going to try to pick up all the trophies I missed my first time around. Unfortunately, there are a few things that I'm close to achieving, but won't quite get to before I finish the game.

In Persona 3, I remember my player's level carrying over, but I don't think this was the case in Persona 4, so I'm hoping that it does in Persona 5 (to minimize time spent training and not increasing Social Links).

What all carries over into New Game+ in Persona 5? What doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://megamitensei.wikia.com/wiki/New_Game_Plus), Persona 5's New Game+ carries over the following:

> - Human parameters, the five status
> - Persona compendium
> - Equipment, including teammates'
> - Money
> - Skill cards
> - Items that unlock persona
> - Items received from maxing co-ops
> - Xmas present
> - Play time
> - Fishing rod
> - Valentine chocolate, or The pity chocolate from the cafe owner

This means that the following things are *not* carried over into New Game+:

> - Name
> - Game difficulty (Player can re-decide)
> - MC's and teammates' level
> - Consumable items
> - Co-op ranks
> - MC's personas
> - Tutorial and Story cut scene history
> - Materials for crafting
> - Presents (for Co-op)
> - Books

Thus, to address the part about player level, this will be reset, but you can potentially buy back your end-game level personas as soon as you start, so even though your player level will be reset, you'll have extremely powerful personas.

That said, a good tip for preparing for New Game+ would be to focus on getting your Social stats as high as possible, since those *do* carry over. The less time spent raising Charm or Guts will be more time spent increasing your Social Links!